# Constraint Problems (scrollview does not appear in iPhone7 and 7+ but does in SE)

Tags: iphone, swift, storyboard

I have a view controller in which I put a scrollview over the view, and pinned it 0 on all sides. I did give it a little room from the top but it still said 0. Then put a view on top of it which I pinned 0 to all, same as scroll view, but made height 600 (instead of 568 I think) I then cntrl clicked from the view to the parent view of the viewcontroller and set equal widths. Now I made the viewcontroller a freeform with a width of 320 (original, I did not change it) and height of 600. I put a few button and text views along with 2 views on the view (view on top of scrollview) So when I built and ran it on my iPhone 5c it looked amazing (in my opinion (: ) But when I changed the device to an iPhone 7 or 7+, the scrollview did not appear. I could not scroll on the simulator. Kind of bummed this happened and checked out my views and could not figure it out, if you can help that would be so great. Here are some pictures (rep not 10 so I can not post picture) Here are the links of the photos. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YoYO.jpg - iphone 7 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFR0e.jpg - iphone se

Thanks guys.

Comment: As I can see, the problem is not with any scrollview. You have to center the textviews inside it.

Comment: Juan Curt should I just center each text field in view or both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: I will answer all the details to fix this. Give me a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the iPhone 7 screen look the same as the iPhone 5, try this:

- Login button: add left constraint to margin
- Sign up button: add right constraint to margin
- Email label, email textview, password label, password textview: centered vertically
- Big login button: bottom constraint 0

That should work. Be free to play with constraints and auto layout, and you should see the same layout in different resolutions, even in iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Try put view (Content View) at scrollView pinned 0 to all, and equal width to main view. Also "Content View" need to know own height.

[image: Content View]

[image: Pins elements]